# How to fix asp.net runtime error 

Tags: c#, asp.net

So i have a page that is suppose to display various reports. This works fine when i run the application with the old reports. However when i run the application with new versions of the reports i get this error.

```
        ASP.NET runtime error: The base class includes the field 'reportViewer',
     but its type (CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer) 
    is not compatible with the type of control 
(CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer).
```

From what I've gathered looking for a solution for this error, it has something to do with CR(Crystal Reports) running either a different or newer version. However From what i know, i haven't changed or updated CR.

The versions i have stored in my web.config for the references i am using with crystal reports are:

```
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=12.0.1100.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Report, Version=12.0.1100.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=12.0.1100.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=12.0.1100.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore, Version=12.0.1100.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Viewing.ReportSource, Version=12.0.1100.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
```

A solution i was given by the previous developer was to modify the .csproj file manually and replace the version # with the correct one which is version 12. Although, this leads me to having an error with VS to be unable to locate the System.Web.Extentions.dll.

So what i would like to know, is what exactly is wrong with my application and how can i rectify the problem.

Comment: Did you modify the target framework version when adjusting the csproj contents? That can lead for an inability to load System.* DLLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think step one should be to uninstall every version of crystal you have on your development machine and only install the exact same one that is present on the server.

If the previous developer says to manually modify the .csproj then it stands to reason that you either have the wrong version or you have multiple versions and it's getting confused somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message when my app was loading the same assembly twice. I think we were using CAB to load the assemblies. At some point the list of assemblies CAB needed to load contained every assembly twice, once in 8.3 file name format and again in long file name format. CAB thought they were different assemblies and loaded them both. I can't recall how that happened. But when we fixed that the problem above went away.